# how to create dynamic array of class simple way?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, dynamic

I am a newbie i just want to know that how to make a array of class dynamically and use that array in different functions which are also in the class.
for example.

```
class customer
{
protected:
    string name;
    int ph_no;

public:
    add(){};
    show(){};
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<customer> v;
```

Comment: so can also use this array in functions witout any problem @humamhelfawi